# AS3 Dynamic Application Saving and Retrieving Data to XML via MovieClip

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, object, flash-cs4, oop

I am creating an application in Flash CS4 that will load data from an XML file and add a movieClip for each item to the stage. Each movie clip contains a NumericStepper component and Input text field.

The user needs to be able to change the fields and update the XML file for the event.CHANGE event.

The XML file needs to be formed like this. I need to be able to navigate between sections and load the data for each one.

```
<sections>
   <section>
       <data>
           <data1></data1>
           <data2></data2>
       </data>
   </section>
   <section>
       <data>
           <data1></data1>
           <data2></data2>
       </data>
   </section>
   <section>
       <data>
           <data1></data1>
           <data2></data2>
       </data>
   </section>
</sections>
```

I don't expect anyone to program it for me. I just need a push in the right direction. I using the Object Oriented Programming methods with a Document class and movieClip classes to control my application. I have been spinning my tires creating several crippled versions. I might be looking at it all wrong. Hopefully someone can shed some light on techniques for creating AS3 applications.

Thanks Guys,

-Laurence

Comment: I don't think is clear what you want to do and what is that we should answer here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use a class to load the XML and create an array of the respective XML values. I can then use this array to manipulate and store data before saving it to XML again. Thanks